# Mongodb Mapreduce giving an error

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a set of data in mapreduce.. 1000000 records for random formdata collected.. 
The data structure is as follows :

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813ef940d9e6"), "clientid" : 5, "FormData" : { "emailadress" : "SWV" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813efb40d9e6"), "clientid" : 4, "FormData" : { "key1" : "VCYU", "key" : "PJO" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813efc40d9e6"), "clientid" : 4, "FormData" : { "key1" : "NJ", "key" : "BZ" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813efd40d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "AY", "first" : "B" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0041d9e6"), "clientid" : 4, "FormData" : { "key1" : "X", "key" : "QPIQ" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0241d9e6"), "clientid" : 5, "FormData" : { "emailadress" : "K" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0341d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "EJ", "first" : "K" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0441d9e6"), "clientid" : 5, "FormData" : { "emailadress" : "X" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0541d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "B", "first" : "G" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0641d9e6"), "clientid" : 4, "FormData" : { "key1" : "BWUE", "key" : "UJ" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0741d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "Q", "first" : "K" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0941d9e6"), "clientid" : 5, "FormData" : { "emailadress" : "IRH" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0b41d9e6"), "clientid" : 5, "FormData" : { "emailadress" : "VCMYE" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0c41d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "LZ", "first" : "L" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0d41d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "X", "first" : "YS" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e0e41d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "IA", "first" : "QT" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e1041d9e6"), "clientid" : 2, "FormData" : { "last" : "GZ", "first" : "MM" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e1141d9e6"), "clientid" : 3, "FormData" : { "phonenumber" : "G", "userid" : "KU", "key" : "KQ" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e1241d9e6"), "clientid" : 3, "FormData" : { "phonenumber" : "E", "userid" : "NU", "key" : "ZHP" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d9c8318cbb7813e1341d9e6"), "clientid" : 4, "FormData" : { "key1" : "FUYV", "key" : "GZ" } }
```

My map function is

```
function () {
    this.FormData.forEach(function (z) {emit(this.clientid, {count:1, datalength:1});});
}
```

My reduce function is :

```
function (key, vals) {
    var result = {count:0, datalength:0};
    vals.forEach(function (value) {result.count += value.count;result.datalength = value.datalength;});
    return result;
}
```

When i run db.clientdata.mapReduct(m,m2) i get

```
Wed Apr  6 15:09:35 uncaught exception: map reduce failed: {
    "assertion" : "map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.FormData.forEach is not a function nofile_b:1",
    "assertionCode" : 9014,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using count and datalength if they have the same value?  Seems like you just need to use count.

Map Function:

```
function () {
   emit(this.clientid, {count:1});
}
```

Reduce Function:

```
function (key, vals) {
    var result = {count:0};
    vals.forEach(function (value) {result.count += value.count;});
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I know they have the same value for now.. I have other plans for it later :)

Comment: Okay, well you can just add it to the form I've provided above.  Your map function is in completely the wrong format, as clientID is not actually a property of formData, and then in addition to this forEach can't be used to iterate over object properties.

Comment: ok assuming we remove the client id, what is the right method to iterate over the properties of the contents of FormData

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to do, but my best guess is that you want to still group by this.clientID, but then have an emit() for each element in form data.  So have a loop like for (val in this.formData) { emit(this.clientID, {count: 1, datalength: val.length}) } .

Answer (score 1):

[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a method of `Array`, not any arbitrary object literal. You cannot use it to iterate over object properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am new to Mongo..This was from a java object.. pretty much a clientId and a Map<String, String> fields.. What is the right method to iterate a "Map"(?) inside mongodb..