# MongoDB map/reduce, forEach is not a function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I am creating a Map function in MongoDB that have a problem as soon as I use forEach() on an array.

This is how a user might look like:

```
"channels" : [
    "Channel 1",
    "Channel 2",
],
"user_id" : "somehash"
```

This is my map function that is causing error:

```
var map = function() {
    if(this.channels && this.user_id) {

        var user_id = this.user_id;

        this.channels.forEach(function(z, user_id) {
            emit(z, {user: user_id});
        });
    }
}
```

When I am running my Map/Reduce in mongo I use the following command and I get also the following error:

```
> db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "myoutput" });
Wed Aug  1 12:48:11 uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
    "assertion" : "map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.channels.forEach is not a function nofile_b:3",
    "assertionCode" : 9014,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I've tried some different approaches and none seem to work, this might be an easy problem but I can't see where I do it wrong.

Would be glad to get some help on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what variable type is *this.channels*, but it seams it's not an array or object.

How are you creating it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5572089/752568

Comment: I am creating it in php with the mongo extension and it looks like this: `array('channels' => $channels)` and `$channels` look like this: `array('channel 1', 'channel 2')`

Comment: the issue is not in the PHP it's in the **JavaScript**.
if you do `typeof(variable)` it should tell you what is `this.channel`

Comment: Yeah it seems like it is an object. How come btw? And can I do this some other way? Can I convert it to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using **for** instead of **forEach**, since it still was a vector I could use `.length` on it.

Solution:

```
var map = function() {
    if(this.channels && this.user_id) {
        var user_id = this.user_id;
        for(var i = 0, imax = this.channels.length; i<imax; i++) {
            emit(this.channels[i], {user: user_id});
        }   
    }
}
```